# Nodemon throwing error: address already in use <port number> on M1 Mac

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm trying to use nodemon on my macbook and whenever i run

```
nodemon <script.js>
```

It gives me this error:

```
address already in use <PORT NUMBER HERE>
```

Even if i'm running the script for the very first time. I've tried

```
npx kill-port <port>
```

But it doesn't work: it shows that a process was killed but when i try to run nodemon again, i get the same error.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

My server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();
dotenv.config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.get("/getRestaurants", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Get All Restaurants");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And my .env:

```
PORT = 4000;
```

What could be causing this? I'm on a M1 MBA with bigsur.